# AngularJS & Google Data Highlighter

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess, seo, sitemap, google-search-console

I developed a Single Page App with AngularJS and I try to deal with SEO troubles. I use html5  to design my URL's with this configuration :

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

With this conf, the refresh will not work because the browser will looking for the page on the server, which doesn't exist. So I added that in my .htaccess which works perfectly:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*) www/index.html [L]
```

And here comes the trouble when I try to improve my SEO via Google Webmaster Tool. With Fetch as google, it works great ! But when I use Data Highlighter to add some ratings, description, nothing work. I explain, something is loaded but it's only the home page (the default route defined in my app.js).

**Does Fetch as Google work the same way as Data Highlighter ?**

**Data Highlighter accepts to deal with pages wich are indexed only, does that mean all my pages which are indexed look like my home page ?**

**To top it all, I have only 1 page indexed in the Index Status sub-menu, is it normal whereas I added 20 url's in my sitemap.xml ?**